# Ionic hang when run ionic serve and error at lint finished in 5.98 s

Tags: android, ionic-framework

this is when i run ionic serve, and hang at lint finished
    C:\workspace\myApp (master -> origin)
    λ ionic serve
    Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser -

```
Ctrl+C to cancel
[17:59:25]  watch started ...
[17:59:25]  build dev started ...
[17:59:25]  clean started ...
[17:59:25]  clean finished in 16 ms
[17:59:25]  copy started ...
[17:59:26]  copy finished in 670 ms
[17:59:26]  deeplinks started ...
[17:59:26]  deeplinks finished in 28 ms
[17:59:26]  transpile started ...
[17:59:37]  transpile finished in 11.26 s
[17:59:37]  preprocess started ...
[17:59:37]  preprocess finished in 2 ms
[17:59:37]  webpack started ...
[17:59:48]  webpack finished in 11.52 s
[17:59:48]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[17:59:51]  sass finished in 2.90 s
[17:59:51]  postprocess started ...
[17:59:51]  postprocess finished in 33 ms
[17:59:51]  lint started ...
[17:59:51]  build dev finished in 26.60 s
[17:59:52]  watch ready in 27.00 s
[17:59:52]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://10.100.95.80:8100
     DevApp: myApp@8100 on DESKTOP-9D89Q03

[17:59:57]  lint finished in 5.12 s
```

hang after that

this is my ionic info

```
λ ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\NgimpiModol\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.9.4
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 10
```

but the project is run at browser google chrome, please help me...

Comment: ok thx a lot brader...

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify what exactly you mean with "it hangs after lint finished"? That just means that the Development Server is up and running and you should be good to go. Is livereload not working?